# How to label/color multiple plots, generated by Table?

Tags: plotting

I have plotted

```
    Clear[Expr1, Expr2]

    Expr1 = x*(1/Sin[Pi x/2])^α


(* x Csc[(π x)/2]^α *)

Expr2 = Normal[Series[Expr1, {x, 0, 5}]]


(* (1/
      x)^α ((2/π)^α x + 
       1/3 2^(-3 + α) π^(2 - α) x^3 α + 
       1/45 2^(-7 + α) π^(4 - α)
         x^5 α (2 + 5 α)) *)

Plot[
     Table[{Expr1, Expr2}, {α, -1, 1, 0.25}], {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotLegends -> Table[α, {α, -1, 1, 0.25}]]
```

but all plots appeared in one color and with one legend key

[image]

how to fix?

Comment: Use the `Evaluated ->True` Option

Comment: @Suzan Cioc Please edit questions to contain only relevant information.  Your comments are "noise."

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick fix:

```
tbl = Table[{Expr1, Expr2}, {\[Alpha], -1, 1, 0.25}];
leg = Table[\[Alpha], {\[Alpha], -1, 1, 0.25}];

Plot[tbl, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> leg]
```

which seems to work:
[image]

Comment: Huh?! I don't have M handy to check, but `Plot[Table[...], ...]` returns all in one color, while `tbl=Table[...]; Plot[tbl...]` works fine? I'd have always put an `Evaluate` such as `Plot[Evaluate@tbl...]`